# Actual vs Budget variance Crystal Reports repeating columns

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sapb1, crystal-reports-8.5

I am new to Crystal reporting. I am trying to join multiple tables I have properly working queries but when I try to add them in SAP CR editor. One of the column shows up fine but others start repeating values.

**I am using the following tables:**

- Budget A/C Code           --**OACT, AccName** --   Budget Relevant A/C Name
- Current Month Actual      --  **OJDT join JDT1**  --  Pick From JE
- Current Month Budget    --  **OBGT Join BGT1**--  Pick From Budget
- Current Month Variance      --  **JDT1 -  BGT1** --   Difference b/w Current Month Actual and Current Month Budget
- Year To Date Actual       --    **Sum of JDT1**     --     Total PnL Balance for the current fiscal year
- Year To Date Budget         --  **Sum of  BGT1**    --  Total Budget Balance for the current fiscal year
- Year to Date Variance     --**Actual -  Budget**  --Difference b/w Year to Date Actual and Year to Date  Budget

**Report format list of columns I want to display:**

- Account Names
- Current Month Actual
- Current Month Budget
- Current Month Variance
- Year to Date Actual
- Year to Date Budget
- Year to Date Variance

**What I have done:**

```
    SELECT
    sum (T1.DebLTotal) actual,
    SUM(T3.Debit) budget,
    **OACT.AcctName ?**

    from
    OBGT T0  INNER JOIN BGT1 T1 ON T0.[AbsId] = T1.[BudgId], 
    OJDT T2 INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T2.[TransId] = T3.[TransId]

    group by T3.Account  -- Some how i want to join OACT to get account names from AcctName 
                         -- field of budget relevant accounts Join on acctcode field
```

Comment: If your query does not return duplicate data, then you may not be doing the exact same joining in the report. Or you may need suppression formula on the report. You question does not give an idea what you have achieved.

Comment: I was trying to get results by joining tables like OJDT join JDT1 OBGT join BGT1 and OACT some how but got broken results . Now i am trying to join all tables together but Unable to join OACT. This is how i have joined 4 tables .       SELECT
sum (T1.DebLTotal),
SUM(T3.Debit)

from
OBGT T0  INNER JOIN BGT1 T1 ON T0.[AbsId] = T1.[BudgId], 
OJDT T2 INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T2.[TransId] = T3.[TransId]

group by T3.Account    --  OACT is not joining i want Account names from AcctName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have completes a portion

```
select

  T3.[AcctCode],sum(T1.[Debit]) as Actual, sum(T5.[DebLTotal]) as Budget
  into #abc
  from 

  [dbo].[JDT1]  T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[OJDT]  
  T2 ON T1.[TransId] = T2.[TransId] INNER JOIN 
  OACT T3 ON T1.[Account] = T3.[AcctCode], OBGT T4 
  INNER JOIN BGT1 T5 ON T4.[AbsId] = T5.[BudgId]

  group by T3.AcctCode

  select OACT.AcctName, #abc.Actual, #abc.Budget 
 from OACT ,#abc where #abc.AcctCode=OACT.AcctCode 

  Drop table #abc
```